# Using Special HTML symbols inside ASP Button Controller

Tags: html, asp.net, button, special-characters

I would like to display an arrow inside an ASP Button Controller.

The arrow will display perfectly if I used an HTML button.

```
<button>&#x25B2</button>
```

I know it works because I can insert HTML tags inside `<button>`. But the same will not work with an ASP Button.

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="&#x25B2" />
```

Is there any way to display an arrow inside the ASP button?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you just need a delimiter (;) at the end of the special character:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="&#x25B2;" />
```

or try

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server">&#x25B2;</asp:Button>
```